# kohana based site on a new localhost

Tags: php, kohana, xampp, localhost

i have a kohana based website, and i moved it to another computer. i have installed xampp and changed the httpd.conf accordingly, to point to my new website location. and it points, cause at first it has given me an error regarding the fact that cache directory must be writable. it points to something /web

i have the path in this named web, with a index.php file that defines me the paths to application, modules,etc. a bunch of the index:

```
<?php

  /**
  * The directory in which your application specific resources are located.
  * The application directory must contain the bootstrap.php file.
  *
  * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#application
  */
  $application = '../application';

  /**
   * The directory in which your modules are located.
   *
   * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#modules
   */
   $modules = '../modules';

 /**
  * The directory in which the Kohana resources are located. The system
  * directory must contain the classes/kohana.php file.
  *
  * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#system
  */
  $system = '../system';
```

my problem is: whenever i access the localhost, i get an absolutely empty page. a blank one.no content. no error. (if i make localhost/phpmyadmin i can get into the phpmyadmin platform and see the database there)

what can be the problem??

thank you

Comment: have u enabled warnings and errors ?

Comment: yes, in bootstrap i have errors TRUE

Comment: What OS is the computer running on?

Comment: 1. Check your webserver logs for errors; 2. Try to set `errors` param in bootstrap.php into FALSE;

Comment: in my log i have [Tue Apr 12 18:12:48 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /users/dananicula/Sites/mnib/web/.DS_Store
[Tue Apr 12 18:12:48 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /users/dananicula/Sites/mnib/web/.htaccess
[Tue Apr 12 18:20:47 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Apr 12 18:20:59 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 12 18:21:00 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...

Comment: changing bootstrap err to false doesn;t change anything. may it be a problem of configuration?

Comment: Looks like a vhost configuration error. Read this article http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start benchmarking

make a separate file and do any error in it and run and check is it showing any error ?

Because it is must here to get error message if it is not working.

Without that It is hard to resolve it.

Comment: the problem is that the exactly same site works fine online. i guess is a problem of configuration but i dunno how to manage it. in the error log i have: [Tue Apr 12 18:12:48 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /users/dananicula/Sites/mnib/web/.DS_Store
[Tue Apr 12 18:12:48 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /users/dananicula/Sites/mnib/web/.htaccess
[Tue Apr 12 18:20:47 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Apr 12 18:20:59 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not ..etc

Answer (score 0):

First test whether the path given is perfect, by install.php,
normally the writable of cache and logs comes when there are no such folders or there is permission issue(for eg in linux).

So, my opinion first check the path using install.php if u don't have u can take it from fresh copy of kohana.

It's the path issue what you are facing.
and later if path are proper than in .htaccess on the display_errors

php_value display_errors 1